# Min reqs for full access to Facebook graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

So Twitter was a stroll in the park, Facebook requires jumping through a few more hoops. I'm not building an "app" per se; all we really need is live access to a small subset of graph api functionality. If that requires publishing a do-nothing "app" on FB for the sole purpose of collecting access tokens, so be it.

A few questions arise:
1. Are all apps to be created via *personal* Facebook accounts, even for businesses?
2. Can/does an app in any way expose the underlying personal account which created it?
3. Is the review process currently a super long, highly invasive rectal exam, or surprisingly smooth?

Thanks and apologies for the non-codey nature of this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, you have to use a Facebook account and you have to apply as developer.
2. No.
3. Depends on the amount of permissions, but in general it is smooth. That is highly opinionated though.

Comment: For point 1, the FB account has to apply for Developer account as well.

Comment: yes, of course. it´s not part of the question, but i will add it.